# Android - RecyclerView Adapter and filter error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I created a RecyclerAdapter that looks like this:

```
public ActiveSubsRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Subscription> activeSubsList) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.activeSubsList = activeSubsList;

    this.activeFiltered = new ArrayList<>();
    this.activeFiltered = activeSubsList;
}
```

Where `activeFiltered` is a List containing filtered objects, which initially contains the whole list.

Then I have a `filter()` method that looks like this:

```
  public void filter(final int category) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //clear filteredActive
            activeFiltered.clear();
            switch (category) {
                case -1:
                    activeFiltered.addAll(activeSubsList);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    for (Subscription sub : activeSubsList) {
                        if (sub.getCategory() == 0) activeFiltered.add(sub);
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    for (Subscription sub : activeSubsList) {
                        if (sub.getCategory() == 1) activeFiltered.add(sub);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    for (Subscription sub : activeSubsList) {
                        if (sub.getCategory() == 2) activeFiltered.add(sub);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    for (Subscription sub : activeSubsList) {
                        if (sub.getCategory() == 3) activeFiltered.add(sub);
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    for (Subscription sub : activeSubsList) {
                        if (sub.getCategory() == 4) activeFiltered.add(sub);
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    for (Subscription sub : activeSubsList) {
                        if (sub.getCategory() == 5) activeFiltered.add(sub);
                    }
                    break;
                case 6:
                    for (Subscription sub : activeSubsList) {
                        if (sub.getCategory() == 6) activeFiltered.add(sub);
                    }
                    break;
                case 7:
                    for (Subscription sub : activeSubsList) {
                        if (sub.getCategory() == 7) activeFiltered.add(sub);
                    }
                    break;
                case 8:
                    for (Subscription sub : activeSubsList) {
                        if (sub.getCategory() == 8) activeFiltered.add(sub);
                    }
                    break;
                case 9:
                    for (Subscription sub : activeSubsList) {
                        if (sub.getCategory() == 9) activeFiltered.add(sub);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            ((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

The adapter is initialized in the main activity like this:

```
private List<Subscription> activeSubs = new ArrayList<>();

adapter = new ActiveSubsRecyclerAdapter(this, activeSubs);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and filter the list in the `main_activity` like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_a: adapter.filter(-1); break;
            case R.id.nav_b: adapter.filter(0); break;
            case R.id.nav_c: adapter.filter(1); break;
            case R.id.nav_d: adapter.filter(2); break;
            case R.id.nav_e: adapter.filter(3); break;
            case R.id.nav_f: adapter.filter(4); break;
            case R.id.nav_g: adapter.filter(5); break;
            case R.id.nav_h: adapter.filter(6); break;
            case R.id.nav_i: adapter.filter(7); break;
            case R.id.nav_j: adapter.filter(8); break;
            case R.id.nav_k: adapter.filter(9); break;
        }
}
```

The problem is that when I filter, no element is displayed.

I tried debugging and got that on both:

```
adapter = new ActiveSubsRecyclerAdapter(this, activeSubs);
```

and on any of the filter cases (e.g):

```
case R.id.nav_a: adapter.filter(-1); break;
```

the `activeSubsList` in `adapter` has size 3 (as expected).

While when I debug on

```
case -1: activeFiltered.addAll(activeSubsList); break;
```

in the `RecyclerAdapter` class, I get that `activeSubsList` has size 0. And that's why the list isn't displayed.

Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Great... now please, tell me why it's been downvoted? So I can improve it

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85) generic `Filterable` adapter as a base class and override its `matches()` method

Comment: so why dont you want to use "generic" adapters? do you want to write that filtering code again and again when creating new adapters?

Comment: @pskink don't really need any more adapters, and this seems to work just fine. I will check out the `Filterable` adapter, I didn't even know about it until now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think the issue is with this line.

```
this.activeFiltered = activeSubsList;
```

Here you are assigning same memory location for both the list, So if you do `activeFiltered.clear();` then the `activeSubsList` will get cleared,

So on the `ActiveSubsRecyclerAdapter` constructor. assign the value by `.addAll()` method.

```
activeFiltered.addAll(activeSubsList);
```

So finally it will look something like

```
public ActiveSubsRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Subscription> activeSubsList) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.activeSubsList = activeSubsList;

    this.activeFiltered = new ArrayList<>();
    this.activeFiltered.addAll(activeSubsList);
}
```

Comment: Yeah this fixed it, was also kind of obvious... How didn't I see that... Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<Subscription> activeSubs = new ArrayList<>();

adapter = new ActiveSubsRecyclerAdapter(this, activeSubs);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

i think problem is here you have initialize the list so it wont be null,but you have nothing in the list and you pass that to adapter,so adapter have nothing in the list and you are trying to filter on empty list.may be that cause you this problem.

**update**

```
activeFiltered = new ArrayList<>();
public ActiveSubsRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Subscription> activeSubsList) {
    this.mContext = context;

    this.activeFiltered = activeSubsList;
}
```

i have update my answer change it and try,let me know.

Comment: No, That's not the whole code. Actually I call this part only when the size of the list is > 0. Also I get the list from sharedPreferences. The size of the list at that point is always > 0

Comment: did you check it with debug?

Comment: that's exactly what I did. It's written in the question.